# Confused about how rails find the actions that does not in current controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This might be a dumb question, please forgive me. I am new to Rails and I google how to locate the actions that not included in current controller but could not figure it out. I noticed that Rails follows the inheritance characteristic. I am confused about how rails finds the 'log_in' method in create action? Since I did not include log_in action in current user controller and neither in user_helper controller and application_helper controller, rails should not find this action at all. Is there any convention that rails will find action in other places?

1.This is normal my user_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :require_login, except:[:new, :create] 

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
    @user = current_user
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        log_in(@user)
        puts @user
        puts session[:user_id]

        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

2. This is my application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
end
```

3. This is my users_helper.rb

```
module UsersHelper
end
```

4. This is my application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :require_login
        def require_login
            if !logged_in?
                redirect_to login_path
            end
        end
end
```

Comment: Are you following any tutorial?

Comment: Hello KKK, and welcome to OS. Posting code with images is a very bad practice. I'd advice you to take your time and post the entire code, well formatted. It will help other people provide you better help.

Comment: Yes！I am following Learnenough Ruby On Rails 6. It does not not explain very clear about when I need to put actions in the helper controller.

Comment: @DaemonPainter Thanks for point that out. I will edit my question to make it more clear for other people!

Comment: Please share your ApplicationController as well.

Comment: @SahilGrover I have post the ApplicationController

Comment: If this is a variant of the RailsTutorial, I think the `log_in` method is defined in a helper named `SessionsHelper` in `app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb`. Helpers are automatically included into controllers, and public methods in helpers are available to both the controller and the view.

Comment: @Unixmonkey Thanks! I guess you are right about sessions_helper.rb which automatically included into controllers. I might accidentally delete the 'include SessionsHelper' in application_controller, and that's why I could not find it. If you make it as official answer, I definitely vote for it!

Answer (score 0):

If this is a variant of the RailsTutorial, [which it looks like from here](https://books.google.com/books?id=0tSmCAAAQBAJ&pg=PT372&lpg=PT372&dq=rails+log_in+method&source=bl&ots=v_KKGf50Td&sig=ACfU3U0YMpTh4kmBjbGNfiqgSzBDdNh36Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiNxeu94JDoAhUHCM0KHbtFAYwQ6AEwB3oECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=rails%20log_in%20method&f=false), I think the `log_in` method is defined in a helper named `SessionsHelper` in `app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb` that looks something like this:

```
module SessionsHelper

  # Logs in the given user
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end
end
```

Helpers are automatically included into controllers, and public methods in helpers are available to both the controller and the view.